# PHP doesnt wait for exec completion

Tags: php, exec

Hi i am trying to execute a php script from cmd with some data given through a GET request but i cant get it to wait for completion of the command for some reason.
The code is.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

file_put_contents("query.txt", $_GET['query']);


exec("php loop1.php");
$result=file_get_contents("result.html");
echo $result;
?>
```

the code of loop1 is too complicated and not the point of the question.

Comment: Did you check if `loop1` is actually being run? If `php` isn't in the path of whatever shell your parent script is invoking, you'll just get a "no such command/filename"error. What's the return value of the exec() call? Try adding the optional 3rd var to exec to capture the exit value of the call

Comment: the optional second var $output might hold clues too

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to run an external PHP script from this PHP script? Why not just do an include and have it run within the current script?

Comment: @MarcB $output=exec("php loop1.php");
I added that, and it seems the output is null. I can run the commad fine from cmd.

Comment: @BenD Yes there is a reason i need to do this, since the data will be used from multiple programs untill the final results are ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the implicit 'php' CLI tool perhaps you would have better luck via the more explicit path for the given install/platform, ie:

```
$phpcli = '/usr/local/bin/php';
exec($phpcli . ' loop1.php');
```

(be sure to first set **$phpcli** to contain the correct explicit path to PHP)

Comment: I changed the code so it doesnt need a get request and ran from cmd, the result was correct, and it waited for exec to complete.
The change is
file_put_contents("query.txt", "WWII");